# is there a way to publish topics of the same node at different rates

Tags: ros, rate, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a single node publishing 5 topics and would like to publish them at different rates. (Python)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261702/is-there-a-way-to-publish-topics-of-the-same-node-at-different-rates/) by [johnd](https://answers.ros.org/users/30383/johnd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-05-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-14**:
Probably not something you'll want to hear, but what have you tried yourself already? How much programming experience do you have? If I say: sure, just use different threads / timer callbacks, does that mean anything to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Timer

```
def update1(event):
    pub1.publish(msg1)

def update2(event):
    pub2.publish(msg2)

def update3(event):
    pub3.publish(msg3)
...

rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1.0 / rate1), update1)
rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1.0 / rate2), update2)
rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1.0 / rate3), update3)
...
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3